# Bootstrap 4 input-group transition width

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, transition

I am trying to animate the width of input in bootstrap 4 nav. The input is part of input-group with a button on the right. I want the input to be hidden and when clicked on the button to expand but the expand happens without any animation.

I'm setting the width of the collapsed input to 0 but there is no animation because of the flex (I guess).

Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nikolakk/1uLotz9r/

I tried:

```
#search {
  input {
    transition: 1s;
  }
  &.collapsed {
    input {
      width: 0;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to use min/max width like this:

```
#search {
  .form-control {
    transition: max-width 1s, min-width 1s;
    max-width: 180px;
    min-width: 180px;
  }
  &.collapsed {
    .form-control {
      max-width: 0;
      min-width: 0;
      width: 0;
    }
  }
```

}

https://jsfiddle.net/ep48qL3d/1/